# Solving two difficult nonlinear equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I have two nonlinear equations with three variables that are derived in a paper. In the paper, the third variable is varied from a certain value to another value and the two other variables are plotted with respect to it. These two equations are *(1)* `abs(C(z,theta1,theta2))=0.1` and *(2)* `diff(abs(C(z,theta1,theta2)),w)=0` where `C(z,theta1,theta2)=A/B` with

```
A=j*(2*(z-1/z)*tan(theta1)+(1/z^2-z^2)*tan(theta1)^2*tan(theta2));

B=2-2*(z+1/z)*tan(theta1)*tan(theta2)-2*tan(theta1)^2+j*(2*(z+1/z)*tan(theta1)+2*tan(theta2)-(1/z^2+z^2)*tan(theta1)^2*tan(theta2));
```

In the two equations above, `j=sqrt(-1)` and `w` is angular frequency; `theta1=w/c*l1` and `theta2=w/c*l2` with `c=3*10^8` and `l1,l2` are lengths. The two equations are at the operating frequency. The authors of the paper, have solved these two equations for the given value of `z` from a certain value like 1.2 to another value like 3 and have plotted the two other variables, `theta1` and `theta2`, with respect to `z`.  The `w` is chosen to be `500*10^6`. Because this is my first post, I can't post image to show the results given in the paper, but the obtained values for `theta1` and `theta2` (`theta1` and `theta2` are electrical lengths in degree) in the range of `z=1.2 to 3`, are about 5 deg. to 30 deg. for `theta2` (a curve like `sqrt(x)`) and about 50 deg. to 10 deg. for `theta1` (a curve like `exp(x)`).

To solve these equations, I started with a fixed value of `z` like `z=1.5` and same operating frequency,`w=500*10^6`. The two resultant equations with these considerations are:

```
equation1=(11.390625*(-3.333333334*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+3.611111112*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(3.25*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+1.5*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2-1.5)^2/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2+5.0625*(-1.666666667*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+1.805555556*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(6.0625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)-9.750*tan(10/3*pi*l1)-4.50*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2)^(1/2)-.1


equation2=1/2*(22.781250*(-3.333333334*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+3.611111112*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))*(3.25*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+1.5*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2-1.5)^2*(-.1111111111e-7*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2407407408e-7*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.1203703704e-7*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2)/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2+22.781250*(-3.333333334*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+3.611111112*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(3.25*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+1.5*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2-1.5)*(.1083333333e-7*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+.1083333333e-7*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2+.1000000000e-7*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1)/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2-22.781250*(-3.333333334*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+3.611111112*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(3.25*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+1.5*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2-1.5)^2*(.4900520833e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2450260417e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2-.3046875000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1-.1015625000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2+.2700000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2700000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2700000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2+.3637500000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.1350000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2)/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^3+10.1250*(-1.666666667*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+1.805555556*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))*(6.0625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)-9.750*tan(10/3*pi*l1)-4.50*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(-.5555555557e-8*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.1203703704e-7*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.6018518520e-8*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2)/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2+10.1250*(-1.666666667*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+1.805555556*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(6.0625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)-9.750*tan(10/3*pi*l1)-4.50*tan(10/3*pi*l2))*(.4041666667e-7*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2020833333e-7*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2-.3250000000e-7*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1-.1500000000e-7*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2)/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2-10.1250*(-1.666666667*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+1.805555556*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(6.0625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)-9.750*tan(10/3*pi*l1)-4.50*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(.4900520833e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2450260417e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2-.3046875000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1-.1015625000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2+.2700000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2700000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.2700000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2+.3637500000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2)*l1+.1350000000e-6*tan(10/3*pi*l2)*(1+tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2)*l2)/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^3)/(11.390625*(-3.333333334*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+3.611111112*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(3.25*tan(10/3*pi*l1)*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+1.5*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2-1.5)^2/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2+5.0625*(-1.666666667*tan(10/3*pi*l1)+1.805555556*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2*(6.0625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)-9.750*tan(10/3*pi*l1)-4.50*tan(10/3*pi*l2))^2/(36.75390625*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2-30.4687500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^3*tan(10/3*pi*l2)+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^4+40.5000*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+54.562500*tan(10/3*pi*l1)^2+20.2500*tan(10/3*pi*l2)^2+20.2500)^2)^(1/2)
```

According to results of the paper, the solutions for `l1` and `l2` with the value of 1.5 for `z`, are approximately 0.02 and 0.06. I used the `solve` function in MATLAB, but the solutions that it gives, are -96 and 220. I used `ezplot` function to see the intersections between two equations and saw that the intersections are numerous for real values of `l1` and `l2`, while according the solution of paper,there is only one solution with the values of 0.02 and 0.06.

Plz guide me what should I do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make it readable. Also, `solve` is for symbolic math. your equations/parameters don't look at all appropriate for a symbolic approach. You should probably be using numerical methods.

Comment: I used the numerical methods,bud because of numerous solutions, the initial guess for solving has very wide range and I don't know which numerical method is suitable for this criteria.